# Installing EASGD Torch luarocks module can't find libmpiT.so?

Tags: ubuntu, lua, deep-learning

I'm going through the instructions here: https://github.com/sixin-zh/mpiT
for installation of the EASGD package.

When I execute luarocks make mpit-mvapich-1.rockspec I receive the error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target mpiT
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mpiT.dir/mpiT.c.o
In file included from /raid/ubuntu/mpiT/mpiT.c:18:0:
/raid/ubuntu/mpiT/lua-mpi.h: In function ‘_MPI_Op’:
/raid/ubuntu/mpiT/lua-mpi.h:51:1: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘luampi_push_MPI_Op’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 MPI_STRUCT_TYPE(Op, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL)
 ^
/raid/ubuntu/mpiT/lua-mpi.h:8:15: note: expected ‘MPI_Op’ but argument is of type ‘struct ompi_datatype_t *’
   static void luampi_push_MPI_##s(lua_State *L, MPI_##s init, int N)    \
               ^
/raid/ubuntu/mpiT/lua-mpi.h:51:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPI_STRUCT_TYPE’
 MPI_STRUCT_TYPE(Op, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL)
 ^
Linking C shared module libmpiT.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpreloadable_libintl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libmpiT.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mpiT.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What's happening?

Edit: tried turning on verbose cmake as recommended by hugomg

```
luarocks make mpit-mvapich-1.rockspec 
cmake -E make_directory build && cd build && cmake .. \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${MPI_PREFIX}/bin/mpicc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${MPI_PREFIX}/bin/mpicxx \
-DMPI_ROOT=${MPI_PREFIX} \
-DOPENMPI=0 \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/bin/.." -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/mpit/mvapich-1" && make

-- Found Torch7 in /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install
MPI ROOT is /usr
LMPI is /usr/lib/libchromeXvMC.so;/usr/lib/libblas.so;/usr/lib/libmpi_f90.so;/usr/lib/libibverbs.so;/usr/lib/libopenblas.so;/usr/lib/libf77blas.so;/usr/lib/libTHC.so;/usr/lib/libijs-0.35.so;/usr/lib/libmpi++.so;/usr/lib/libvdpau_ubuntu.so;/usr/lib/libcr.so;/usr/lib/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/libgettextlib-0.18.3.so;/usr/lib/libGraphicsMagickWand.so;/usr/lib/libopen-pal.so;/usr/lib/preloadable_libintl.so;/usr/lib/libmpi.so;/usr/lib/libsnappy.so;/usr/lib/libmca_common_sm.so;/usr/lib/libgettextsrc-0.18.3.so;/usr/lib/libfreeimage-3.15.4.so;/usr/lib/libopen-rte.so;/usr/lib/libcblas.so;/usr/lib/libluaT.so;/usr/lib/libqtlua.so;/usr/lib/libguilereadline-v-18.so;/usr/lib/libompitrace.so;/usr/lib/libchromeXvMCPro.so;/usr/lib/libopcodes-2.24-system.so;/usr/lib/libatlas.so;/usr/lib/libdsdp-5.8gf.so;/usr/lib/libTH.so;/usr/lib/libpulsecore-4.0.so;/usr/lib/libv8.so;/usr/lib/libGraphicsMagick.so;/usr/lib/libmpi_f77.so;/usr/lib/libmpif90.so;/usr/lib/libfreeimageplus-3.15.4.so;/usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.so;/usr/lib/libbfd-2.24-system.so;/usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.so;/usr/lib/libthreadsmain.so;/usr/lib/libcr_omit.so;/usr/lib/libcr_run.so;/usr/lib/libcompizconfig_gsettings_backend.so;/usr/lib/libqlua.so;/usr/lib/libluajit.so;/usr/lib/libmpif77.so
LMCA is 
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning at /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/share/cmake/torch/TorchPackage.cmake:17 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Cannot generate a safe linker search path for target mpiT because files in
  some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    link library [libTHC.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    link library [libluaT.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    link library [libqtlua.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    link library [libTH.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    link library [libthreadsmain.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    link library [libqlua.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    link library [libluajit.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (ADD_TORCH_PACKAGE)


CMake Warning at /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/share/cmake/torch/TorchPackage.cmake:17 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target mpiT because files in
  some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libTHC.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    runtime library [libluaT.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    runtime library [libqtlua.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    runtime library [libTH.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    runtime library [libthreadsmain.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    runtime library [libqlua.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib
    runtime library [libluajit.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/ubuntu/dltools/distro/install/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (ADD_TORCH_PACKAGE)


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /raid/ubuntu/mpiT/build
Linking C shared module libmpiT.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpreloadable_libintl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libmpiT.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mpiT.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual error is that it cannot find `preloadable_libintl.so`, which is a library that is part of GNU's libc. Try installing the missing dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

or, if that does not work

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried those and they were already installed.  I tried --upgrade too but still the same error.  It's linked incorrectly then or can't find it?

locate preloadable_libintl.so
says that its located at
/usr/lib/preloadable_libintl.so

Comment: Is there a way to see what flags are being passed to gcc and/or ld? I'm not proficient with cmake but I think it should be possible to edit the CMakelists.txt to put it in "verbose" mode